# Modal fade on click link not works

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I 've an issue with Jquery on click and modal fade. When I click on  modal displays correctly, but not fading in and fading out. I tried also adding fade class in modal, but nothing happens.
I tried this code below, but I can't figure out where is mistake. Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<a class="d-flex align-self-end float-right ico_doc" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" id="tasto1" >link</a>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" style="background-color:rgba(33, 37, 41, .15) ">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="closeModal()"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="mySlides" id="prod1">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/600/300" style="width:100%" alt=""> </div>
<div class="mySlides" id="prod2">
<div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1050/600/300" style="width:100%" alt=""> </div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/600/600/300" style="width:100%" alt=""> </div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/87/600/300" style="width:100%" alt=""> </div>
<div class="mySlides">
<div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/600/300" style="width:100%" alt=""> </div>

<!-- Next/previous controls --> 
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a> <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a> 

<!-- Caption text -->
<div class="caption-container">
<p id="caption"></p>
</div>

<!-- Thumbnail image controls striscia di Foto piccole nel MODAL  -->
<div class="row prima_fascia" style="white-space: nowrap;">
<div class="col-md-3 m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center" > <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature" style="width:80%"> </div>
<div class="col-lg-3  m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center"> <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1050/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow" style="width:80%"> </div>
<div class="col-lg-3  m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center"> <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/87/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains" style="width:80%"> </div>
<div class="col-lg-3  m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center"> <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Lights" style="width:80%"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row seconda_fascia " id="demo2">
<div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block"  > <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/500/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature" style="width:100%"> </div>
<div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block"> <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/250/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"> </div>
<div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block"> <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/615/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(7)" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%"> </div>
<div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block"> <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/49/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(8)" alt="Lights" style="width:100%"> </div>
</div>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(e){
         $("#tasto1").on('click',function(){
             $("#myModal").fadeIn(1000)
         });
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have both an `onclick=` and `$("#tasto1").on("click"` - you should probably stick with one or the other so you can tell what's going on.  Try removing the `onclick=openModal()` so that it doesn't open without the fade (guessing what's in openModal)

Comment: In bs4 you can also make the modal fade in without your own code:  `<div class="modal fade"`  (see link on how to remove it, so do the opposite: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#remove-animation)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you :) I tried your solution to remove onclick=openModal() and now modal fade works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery on click function work only on double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64349795/jquery-on-click-function-work-only-on-double-click)

Comment: @Greedo No, are different questions. This question above is about how make modal fading on click.Instead other question is about why my button display modal only when I double click on it and not on one click.