# jquery on click function work only on double click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I have an issue with jquery function on.click.
I have a button and when I double click on it opens a fade in modal, but if I click it once, nothing happens. I can't figure out where I'm doing wrong. The button has an hover effect made with CSS. Could this hover effect might interferring with button click?

Below I post my code. Thanks

```js
function fadeIn() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    $("#tasto1").on('click', function() {
      $("#myModal").fadeIn(600);
    })
  });
}


// Open the Modal


function openModal() {

  /*document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";*/

  document.querySelectorAll(".seconda_fascia").forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
  });
  document.querySelectorAll(".prima_fascia").forEach(function(element) {
    element.style.display = "inline-block";
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="d-flex align-self-end float-right ico_doc btn" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1);fadeIn();" id="tasto1" type="button">
                      <img class="card-img" src="imgs/SVG/ICO_DOC.svg" alt="" loading="lazy"  id="ICO_DOC2x_mq"></button>

<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" style="background-color:rgba(33, 37, 41, .15)    /*  10% opaque green */ ">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl m">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="closeModal()">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="mySlides" id="prod1">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/600/300" style="width:100%" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides" id="prod2">
          <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1050/600/300" style="width:100%" alt="">
        </div>


        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/600/600/300" style="width:100%" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/87/600/300" style="width:100%" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
          <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/600/300" style="width:100%" alt="">
        </div>

        <!-- Next/previous controls -->
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

        <!-- Caption text -->
        <div class="caption-container">
          <p id="caption"></p>
        </div>

        <!-- Thumbnail image controls striscia di Foto piccole nel MODAL  -->
        <div class="row prima_fascia" style="white-space: nowrap;">

          <div class="col-md-3 m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center">
            <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1000/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature" style="width:80%">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3  m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center">
            <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1050/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Snow" style="width:80%">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3  m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center">
            <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/87/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains" style="width:80%">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3  m-0 p-0 d-inline-block text-center">
            <img class="demo" src="https://picsum.photos/id/18/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Lights" style="width:80%">
          </div>


        </div>

        <div class="row seconda_fascia " id="demo2">

          <div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block">
            <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/500/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block">
            <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/250/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block">
            <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/615/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(7)" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-3  d-inline-block">
            <img class="demo2" src="https://picsum.photos/id/49/600/300" onclick="currentSlide(8)" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is not really clear and the code you provided is not working.

I think the issue is in the `fadeIn` function, you attach an event listener at each iteration. Also, at the first click the callback won't be executed, and this seems the
issue you described.

To fix it, you should change the function to:

```
function fadeIn() {
  $("#myModal").fadeIn(600);
}
```

Also, consider about event binding from JS, avoid `onclick` and similar structures and prefer this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tasto1").click(function() {
    openModal();
    currentSlide(1);
    fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) You saved my work. My mistake was I didn't understand how to pass multiple functions in a button.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong use of click events.

```
<button class="d-flex align-self-end float-right ico_doc btn" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1);fadeIn();" id="tasto1" type="button">
```

You have a button where you inline call on click `function function fadeIn() {` witch then sets another click event on same button... That does not make sense at all.

```
function fadeIn() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    $("#tasto1").on('click', function() {
      $("#myModal").fadeIn(600);
    })
  });
}
```

Ether you are going to make a function call inline like you did

```
onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1);fadeIn();"
```

and then do everything you need inside:

```
function fadeIn() {
      $("#myModal").fadeIn(600);
}
```

or you are not going to call it inline and set it with jQuery:

```
onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)"

$("#tasto1").on('click', function() {
  $("#myModal").fadeIn(600);
})
```

Please read about how to [add events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)